# Merge two arrays in Java to maintain the order and with the unique blank values of first array

Tags: java, arrays, merge, array-merge

I have two arrays. I need the blanks for later code.

Both the arrays will have common values and the common values are expected to be in order.

Here we have `Alpha`, `Beta`, `Phi`, and `Gamma`. There are blanks in between in both arrays.

```
String[] a = { " ", "Alpha", "Beta", "Phi", " ", "Gamma" };
String[] b = { "Alpha", " ", "Beta", "Phi", "Gamma", " " };
```

The output should consider the first array i.e. since the first element of the array, `a` is `" "` so the output starts with Blank. The Blank between `Alpha` and `Beta` of the second array and the one after `Gamma` should remain unaltered as that is part of the second array. Additionally since in the first array, `a` there is another `" "` between `Phi` and `Gamma` which does not occur in the second array, `b` hence that is also added in the output. The order of both arrays must remain the same but the positions will change due to the insertion of `" "`.

**Expected output:**

```
[ " ", "Alpha", " ", "Beta", "Phi", " ", "Gamma", " " ]
```

Normal merging is simple and a lot of examples are out there. However, this is something that I am unable to figure out yet.

Any hints or examples will be helpful.

Apologies this somehow turns out to be a duplicate post.

Comment: There are edges cases in your sample. eg, what if `b = { "Alpha", "NoSuch", "Beta", "Phi", "Gamma", " " };` You should provide all cases.

Comment: In that case, it should be 
[ " ", "Alpha", "NoSuch", "Beta", "Phi", " ", "Gamma", " " ] 
However, the scenario that I am working on is not expecting any random value in the second Array b i.e. values like "NoSuch" will not come as it does not exist at all in the first Array a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, k;
        String[] a = { " ", "Alpha", "Beta", "Phi", " ", "Gamma" };
        String[] b = { "Alpha", " ", "Beta", "Phi", "Gamma", " " };

        // Target array
        String[] c = new String[a.length + b.length];

        // Copy the elements from both the source arrays to the target array
        for (i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++) {
            add(c, a[i]);
            add(c, b[i]);
        }

        // Copy the remaining elements from the first source array
        for (k = i; k < a.length; k++) {
            add(c, a[k]);
        }

        // Copy the remaining elements from the second source array
        for (k = i; k < b.length; k++) {
            add(c, b[k]);
        }

        // Discard null elements
        c = trim(c);

        // Display the target array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
    }

    static void add(String[] arr, String s) {
        int i;
        if (" ".equals(s)) {
            // Find the position of first null
            for (i = 0; arr[i] != null && i < arr.length; i++) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            // Replace null with " "
            arr[i] = s;
            return;
        }

        // Return if the string already exists
        for (i = 0; arr[i] != null && i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].equals(s)) {
                return;
            }
        }

        // Replace null with the string
        arr[i] = s;
    }

    static String[] trim(String[] arr) {
        int i;

        // Find the position of first null
        for (i = 0; arr[i] != null && i < arr.length; i++) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        return Arrays.copyOf(arr, i);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[ , Alpha,  , Beta, Phi,  , Gamma,  ]
```

Comment: Though it is close. This is not what I wanted.

Comment: @ShaibayanChakrabarti - What is missing in this solution?

Comment: Nothing is missing but the values are occurring as duplicates in the output.

Comment: @ShaibayanChakrabarti - I've updated the answer. I hope, it fulfils your requirement precisely. Feel free to comment in case of any issue.